# Page builder php errror

Tags: php, web-scraping, magento, error-handling, admin

app/Http/Controllers/Admin/Extensions/PageBuilder/ManagePageBuilderController.php:138

unlink(/home/freedex/public_html/public/pages/css/https://freedex.io/faq.css): No such file or directory

hi, i am getting a php error on the admin page while creating the page.

Can you help me ?

```
When creating a new page in Admin, I was expecting it to create the new page directly with the page extension.
```

Comment: remove `unlink(/home/freedex/public_html/public/pages/css/https://freedex.io/faq.css): ` this line.

Comment: unlink(/home/freedex/public_html/public/pages/css/https://freedex.io/faq.css): No such file or directory it is incorrect path

Comment: edit your question and pass the screenshot of your error, i saw you using a base64 image code